# How to Modify HTTP Header of a request using C#?

Tags: c#, http-headers, namevaluecollection

I was trying to modify a HTTP Header using C#. I tried to manipulate the Request.Headers on Page preinit event. But when i try to set anything to the Headers, i get PlatformNotSupportedException. Since We can not set a new NameValueCollection to Reqeust.Headers, I tried to set the value using following code:

```
Request.Headers.Set(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent.ToString(), "some value");
```

Any idea how can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you really need to set the Request(=incoming) value, or rather the Response one (=outgoing)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["User-Agent"] = "Some Value";
```

**EDIT:** 
This could be your reason:
http://bigjimindc.blogspot.com/2007/07/ms-kb928365-aspnet-requestheadersadd.html

There is a code snippet in that, which adds a new header to the Request.Headers. Verified on Windows 7 32 bit OS too.

But you might want to replace the line:

```
HttpApplication objApp = (HttpApplication)r_objSender;
```

with:

```
HttpApplication objApp = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
```

**EDIT:**
To replace the existing Header value, use:

```
t.InvokeMember("BaseSet", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, headers, new object[] { "Host", item });
```

where "Host" is a Header name.

Comment: I get PlatformNotSupportedException. I use Windows 7 32 Bit with IIS 7.5

Comment: I used the above code on Win Server 2008, IIS 7, .Net Framework 3.5 SP1; and it worked nicely

Comment: For people using System.Net.HttpContent.Headers, I used .Remove() followed by .Add(), in order to produce this behavior.  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Adding the complete (working) code from the linked blog - incase that blog vanishes

```
HttpApplication objApp = (HttpApplication)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance;
HttpRequest Request = (HttpContext)objApp.Context.Request;

//get a reference
NameValueCollection headers = Request.Headers;

//get a type
Type t = headers.GetType();
System.Collections.ArrayList item = new System.Collections.ArrayList();

t.InvokeMember("MakeReadWrite",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,null,headers,null);
t.InvokeMember("InvalidateCachedArrays",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,null,headers,null);
item.Add("CUSTOM_HEADER_VALUE");
t.InvokeMember("BaseAdd",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,null,headers, new object[]{"CUSTOM_HEADER_NAME",item});
t.InvokeMember("MakeReadOnly",BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,null,headers,null);
```