# How to modify values of HTTP header of a request permanently

Tags: c#, http-headers, request-headers, self-modifying, namevaluecollection

I am referring to the below post.

[How to Modify HTTP Header of a request using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975240/how-to-modify-http-header-of-a-request-using-c)

Solution provided here is working fine. But when i do the redirection to another page. All the changes done at request header are being lost. Please help

Comment: Your link is not showing as a link.  Can you fix that?

Comment: Its fixed now @MichaelDotKnox

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do a redirect to another page, it causes the browser to send a new request to the redirected page, so it sends a new set of headers.  It does not send the modified headers that you made before the redirection.

Comment: Do we have any solution to made these changes permanent for quiet sometime? For 2 minutes?

Comment: No, the browser will always send new headers.  The change made in the code in the example you give is making the changes on the server side.  The browser is doing that on the client side.

Comment: Thanks dear @michaelDotKnox